# How to make SVG selectable in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

With TinyMCE I use `extended_valid_elements` to allow SVG elements, and indeed I can then add them, but the SVG elements are not selectable/clickable. I am trying to reach the same behavior as IMG elements - allow selecting, dragging and resizing SVG elements.

I tried looking at TinyMCE sources for "IMG" to figure out what makes them selectable and apply the same to "SVG", but noting I tried worked.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this work fine for me : [image]

Give me the following result :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't mean an uploaded image that originated from SVG file, which results in an IMG DOM element, I meant an SVG DOM element (which would be programmatically added), as opposed to IMG DOM element.